# Краткое причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: части-речи

Он утверждает, что эти обвинения политически мотивированы.

Здесь *мотивированы* краткое причастие? Как определить, прилагательное или причастие?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Он утверждает, что эти обвинения политически мотивированы. Это краткое причастие, потому что:

1.обвинения что сделаны?-мотивированы (их кто-то мотивировал, убедил,привёл мотивы, доводы)

2.написано с одним -н-

3.есть зависимое обстоятельство: мотивированы как? -политически (при прилагательном может быть только наречие степени качества(очень, почти, абсолютно, совершенно))

4.нельзя заменить прилагательным-синонимом.

Сравните:ваши претензии мотивированны - прилагательное, т.к. отвечает на вопрос каковы?, можно заменить прилагательным-синонимом  законны,их никто не мотивировал, они содержат мотив в себе, пишется с -нн-

Мы молоды, амбициозны и абсолютно мотивированны - прилагательное,т.к. отвечает на вопрос каковы?, входит в ряд однородных членов-прилагательных, при нём есть наречие степени качества, можно заменить прилагательным целеустремлённы, пишется с -нн-

Comment: Людмила, я ждала Вашего ответа (как знала, что именно Вы ответите). :) Я первые три пункта определила тоже, но в синонимах совершенно запуталась. Вы прояснили ситуацию :)

Comment: Спасибо, звучит как комплимент. Приятно, что кому-то могу помочь. Вот только автор ответ почему-то не принимает. Может, ему не нравится? Или не считает нужным прореагировать?

Comment: У Вас действительно хорошие ответы. Автор, скорее всего, в опциях не разобрался или еще не заходил. Я, честно говоря, тоже не знаю, как принять ответ. Могу только "лайк" поставить.

Comment: принять - это выбрать под понравившимся ответом кружочек с галочкой.

Comment: Спасибо, нашла

Comment: (при прилагательном может быть только наречие степени качества(очень, почти, абсолютно, совершенно))

диаметрально противоположный, прямо противоположный, чисто русский, детски наивный

здесь при прилагательных наречия, но они не являются наречиями степени качества.
оппозиционно настроенный журналист. Здесь настроенный прилагательное или причастие?

Answer (score 2):

КОГДА ПРИЧАСТИЕ ПЕРЕХОДИТ В ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ

Различать причастия и прилагательные нужно не только по формальным признакам, но и по существу. Изначально глагольная форма является причастием, но в некоторых случаях МОЖЕТ ПЕРЕЙТИ в прилагательное.  При этом причастие теряет временной признак и производителя действия, а в своем новом статусе приобретает постоянное (ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ) значение, ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ иметь наречия степени и вступать в однородные отношения с прилагательными. Его также можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным.  (Все остальные наречия, кроме наречий степени, оно также может иметь).

МОТИВИРОВАННЫЙ

Глагольная форма «мотивированный» может быть причастием или прилагательным. (Словарь подсказывает нам, что возможны краткие формы прилагательного «мотивированны, мотивированна»). Прилагательное  «мотивированный» имеет значение «обоснованный, убедительный, правильный, законный и др.».  "Ваши требования абсолютно правильны, законны и мотивированны" (это прилагательное). "Исковые требования мотивированы тем, что…" (это причастие).
А мотивированные (целеустремленные) люди?  Пока это прилагательное, так как значение переносное: можно мотивировать отказ, но нельзя мотивировать людей. Если в словаре появится такое значение, то мы будем иметь причастие.

ОППОЗИЦИОННО НАСТРОЕННЫЙ ЖУРНАЛИСТ

Глагол «настроить»  имеет старшее значение «отрегулировать, привести в рабочее состояние», а также ПЕРЕНОСНЫЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ «привести в определенное настроение, внушить что-то».  Поэтому «оппозиционно настроенный» – это причастие (у него нет необходимости переходить в прилагательное), а краткая форма пишется с одной буквой Н: они оппозиционно настроены.

МОТИВИРОВАННЫ И НАСТРОЕНЫ

Разница между «они мотивированны» и  «они настроены» заключается в том, что в первом случае переносное значение имеет причастие, перешедшее в прилагательное, а во втором случае переносное значение имеет сам глагол.